# Attempting to "turn on/off" different UITapGestureReconginzer methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have this lovely nav bar asset:

[navBar view http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734050/ViewWithNavBar.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734050/ViewWithNavBar.jpg)

and when users tap on the middle button (one with the arrows) it will bring up this other lovely "share box" asset

[shareBox dropdown from navBar http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734050/navBarWithShareBox.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734050/navBarWithShareBox.jpg)

What I have in the code so far is that when the screen is tapped, the nav bar will appear, and disappear on another tap. Secondly, when the user taps on the "share" button, the share box comes up, and the user can tap outside of the box to dismiss it.

Here is the problem: I cannot dismiss the nav bar after bringing up the share box!

Here is some code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

...
...
...

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapNavBar = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForNavBar:)];
    self.tapForNavBar = tapNavBar;

    [self.viewForTaps addGestureRecognizer:self.tapForNavBar];

    // btw, tapForNavBar is a UITapGestureRecognizer instance variable.
    // also, viewForTaps is a view (instance variable) I made to handle 
    // where the user could tap (most of the screen)

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tap and Gesture Methods

-(void)handleTapForNavBar:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (self.navBarIsHidden) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            //self.primeViewController.view.alpha = 0.8;
            self.navBar.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
        self.detailViewButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.shareButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.aboutAppButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.navBarIsHidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            self.navBar.alpha = 0.0;
            //self.primeViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
        self.detailViewButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.shareButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.aboutAppButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.navBarIsHidden = YES;
    }   

}
```

Ok, so that should look all dandy (and works like it too!) -- now here is perhaps where it gets unorthodox?

```
-(IBAction)showShareMenu:(id)sender {

    if (self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            self.navBarShareBox.alpha = 1.0;
        }];  
        [self.tapForNavBar removeTarget:nil action:NULL];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapShareBox = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForShareBox:)];
        self.tapForShareBox = tapShareBox;

        [self.viewForTaps addGestureRecognizer:self.tapForShareBox];
        self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden = NO;
        self.twitterButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.facebookButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.googlePlusButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            self.navBarShareBox.alpha = 0.0;
        }];  
        [self.tapForShareBox removeTarget:nil action:NULL];
        [self.tapForNavBar addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForNavBar:)];
        self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden = YES;
        self.twitterButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.facebookButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.googlePlusButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

I then create this method to handle the specific shareBox tapping:

```
-(void)handleTapForShareBox:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (!self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            self.navBarShareBox.alpha = 0.0;
        }];
        self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden = YES;
        self.twitterButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.facebookButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.googlePlusButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.tapForShareBox removeTarget:nil action:NULL];
        [self.tapForNavBar addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForNavBar:)];
    }

}
```

I'm assuming my problem is coming from `alloc`/`init`ing the new `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the `-(IBAction)showShareMenu` method. I thought by using the `removeTarget`... and `addTarget` messages I could easily tell my code which TapGesture method it should use, but considering it isn't working, I was wrong! Where did I go wrong? If you need more info, I'd be happy to give more.

Comment: Thanks so much @JoshCaswell I guess I didn't sleep enough to see all of my silly errors ಠ_ಠ (@ myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah Ha! Looks like I found a solution! In my `handleTapForShareBox` method I did this:

```
-(void)handleTapForShareBox:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (!self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
            self.navBarShareBox.alpha = 0.0;
        }];
        self.navBarShareBoxIsHidden = YES;
        self.twitterButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.facebookButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.googlePlusButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.tapForShareBox removeTarget:nil action:NULL];
        //[self.tapForNavBar addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForNavBar:)];

        // Here is the new stuff, I added another alloc init of a UITapGestureRecognizer
        // and re-assigned it to my UITap instance variable

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapNavBar = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapForNavBar:)];
        self.tapForNavBar = tapNavBar;

        [self.viewForTaps addGestureRecognizer:self.tapForNavBar];
    }
}
```

It works great now! However, there were a couple things:

1) Do I have to release the UITapGestureRecognizer local pointer I created? Or because I `initWithTarget` it will be autoreleased?

2) Is this a hack? Or is this a proper way of passing different tap methods around? I'm just a little confused why the `removeTarget` and `addTarget` didn't do the trick.